# oracle loop ordering

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I have loop script by pl/sql, my script returned order by i asc,

```
DECLARE 
    i NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT 1 as i from dual
        UNION
        SELECT 2 as i from dual
        UNION
        SELECT 3 as i from dual
        UNION
        SELECT 4 as i from dual
    )
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (rec.i); 
    END LOOP; 
end;
```

and it returned

```
1
2
3
4
```

but I need ordering

```
1
4
3
2
```

what function should I use to solve the problem, thank you advence

Comment: It's the SQL part that controls the ordering - the loop just processes the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Main starting reference point of interest for indexing may be `i-1` in the order by part of the sql statement.

So, the following cursor may be prefered :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT 1 as i from dual
 UNION
 SELECT 2 as i from dual
 UNION
 SELECT 3 as i from dual
 UNION
 SELECT 4 as i from dual
)
ORDER BY sign(i-1), (i-1) desc;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1808/9)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to return what you want:

```
DECLARE 
    i NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT 1 as i from dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 as i from dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 as i from dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 as i from dual
     ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (rec.i); 
    END LOOP; 
end;
```

However, that is just because the data is small.  Oracle doesn't guarantee the ordering of result sets without an `ORDER BY`.  So a safer method is:

```
DECLARE 
    i NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT i
        FROM (SELECT 1 as i, 1 as ord from dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 4 as i, 2 from dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 3 as i, 3 from dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 as i, 4 from dual
             ) x
        ORDER BY ord
     ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (rec.i); 
    END LOOP; 
end;
```

Comment: I want to change ordering in loop, but not select statment

Comment: for example DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (mod(rec.i,4)-1 returned 2,3,4,1 - 4 is count rows

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **UNION** operator use **UNION ALL** operator because **UNION** operator return **sorted distinct** result. On the other hand **UNION ALL** operator return **duplicate unsorted** result

try the below query:-

`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
    i NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT 1 as i from dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 as i from dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 as i from dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 as i from dual
     ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (rec.i); 
    END LOOP; 
end;
/`

Comment: I want to change ordering in loop, but not select statment